# Add exception to natural sorting in datatables

Tags: datatables

Is there a way to add exceptions to the [natural ordering plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/natural), so that it ignores things like `c.` , `[`, `]`, `?` ?

This is an example of my data:

161?
1604
[1563]
c. 1476

I'd like the sorted asc. output to be:

c. 1476
[1563]
1604
161?

Right now what I get is all the numbers first, and the strings beginning with `[` afterwards.

My initialisation code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.24/sorting/natural.js"></script>

$('#sourcesList').DataTable({
          "paging": false,
          "columnDefs": [
            { type: 'natural-nohmtl', targets: '_all' }
          ],
[...]
```

PS: [this is my data](https://hms.scot/prints/sources/) in the wild.

Comment: For clarification: You want to sort on the numeric portion of each field - but even then you still want to use alphanumeric ordering? So 1604 is sorted before 161 (because you want to treat the values as strings not numbers)?

Comment: That's a good point. OK, let's forget about the `161?` for now, one thing at a time. What about the square brackets and the `c. `? My understanding is that natural sorting should take care of mixture of strings and numbers. I only want it to take care of numbers, ignoring strings.

Comment: PS: I've added a link to my table at the end of my question so you can better see what kind of data we're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The natural sorting option takes care of certain types of numeric data which you can reasonably expect to encounter in the "real world" - such as numbers with different thousands separators, or with currency symbols of different types in different positions - or "1st", "2nd" "3rd" and so on. Don't quote me on these exact examples, as I have not looked at that add-on in detail. But that is the overall idea.

Items such as question-marks - I would not expect that add-on to handle those. Items in square brackets - same thing.

Given your clarification in a comment, I think you do not need or want this add-on.

Instead you can use a column renderer with DataTables' ability to store [different versions of a value](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) - for display, sorting, and filtering.

```
var dataSet = [ ["161?"], ["1604"], ["[1563]"], ["c. 1476"] ];
 
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columnDefs: [ { 
          type: "natural-nohmtl", 
          targets: [ 0 ],
          title: "My Data",
          "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
            if ( type === 'sort' ) {
              //return parseInt(data.replace(/\D/g, '')); // numbers as numbers
              return data.replace(/\D/g, ''); // numbers as strings
            } else {
              return data;
            }
          }
        } ]
    } );
    
} );
```

This saves a version of each value with all non-digits stripped from the value, using `replace(/\D/g, '')`. This altered version of the data is stored as the value which will be used when sorting. The unaltered version is what the user will see.

My result:

[image]

This is the case where numbers are treated as text.

You can uncomment the commented-out `return` statement to get numbers as numbers.

*However...*

This crude approach of stripping non-digits from the data meets the narrow example from your question, but it may not be sufficient for all the data you are expecting to handle. So, you may need to refine the "replace" logic.

But the render function should meet your needs, more generally.

Comment: I saw your real world data after writing this answer. So, that point about my crude demo definitely applies: You are going to need some more targeted logic to handle specific cases such as "18--", and so on (for example, to replace the "--" with "00") before applying my more general replace logic.

Comment: This is great infromation, thank you. But how can I apply it if the data is coming from elsewhere? This is a Django project where the data is filled via the view-template system. Is there any other way without using the data: `dataSet instruction`?

Comment: I'm accepting your solution because it shows effort, clarity of information, and it's valid. It also put me on the right track. I should have specified that I'm not loading my data with ajax. Nevertheless the link you provided about the 'orthogonal data' gave me the idea of using a custom Django template filter which puts the stripped strings into a `data-order` HTML 5 attribute, which then allows the column to be sortable as I want.