# DataTables - Sort column by numbers and letters

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I can't sort column 0 of the datatable.

See that it is out of order

Where I need:
1st
2nd
3rd
...
10th

Even in ascending and descending order the listing is not correct.

I didn't find a solution on google and in the forum.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
            "iDisplayLength": 50,
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "responsive": true,
    } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
            <td>9º (2017 a 2020)</td>
            <td>2º (2019 a 2020)</td>
            <td class="center">18/08/2021 às 23:49:02</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td>9º (2017 a 2020)</td>
            <td>1º (2017 a 2018)</td>
            <td class="center">18/08/2021 às 23:48:49</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
            <td>8º (2013 a 2016)</td>
            <td>2º (2015 a 2016)</td>
            <td class="center">18/08/2021 às 23:48:39</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td>8º (2013 a 2016)</td>
            <td>1º (2013 a 2014)</td>
            <td class="center">18/08/2021 às 23:48:29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
            <td>7º (2009 a 2012)</td>
            <td>2º (2011 a 2012)</td>
            <td class="center">18/08/2021 às 23:48:19</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td>7º (2009 a 2012)</td>
            <td>1º (2009 a 2010)</td>
            <td class="center">18/08/2021 às 23:48:08</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
            <td>6º (2005 a 2008)</td>
            <td>2º (2007 a 2008)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:21:20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td>6º (2005 a 2008)</td>
            <td>1º (2005 a 2006)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:20:15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
            <td>5º (2001 a 2004)</td>
            <td>2º (2003 a 2004)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:22:09</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td>5º (2001 a 2004)</td>
            <td>1º (2001 a 2002)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:21:44</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
            <td>4º (1997 a 2000)</td>
            <td>2º (1999 a 2000)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:23:49</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td>4º (1997 a 2000)</td>
            <td>1º (1997 a 1998)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:22:39</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
            <td>3º (1993 a 1996)</td>
            <td>2º (1995 a 1996)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:24:45</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td>3º (1993 a 1996)</td>
            <td>2º (1995 a 1996)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:25:39</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
            <td>3º (1993 a 1996)</td>
            <td>1º (1993 a 1994)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:24:21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td>3º (1993 a 1996)</td>
            <td>1º (1993 a 1994)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:25:18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
            <td>10º (2021 a 2024)</td>
            <td>2º (2023 a 2024)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:18:35</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td>10º (2021 a 2024)</td>
            <td>1º (2021 a 2022)</td>
            <td class="center">18/08/2021 às 23:49:12</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th>ANO</th>
            <th>BIÊNIO</th>
            <th>DATA DE CADASTRO</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

```
SELECT
   `year`,
   `biennium`,
   `data_registration`
FROM
   `table`
ORDER BY CAST(`year` AS UNSIGNED) ASC;
```

Since in mysql I can make the listing I want.
However, when clicking to order in the column, it is out of order.

Comment: There are various ways to handle this. One is to use [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data#Computed-values) in a column renderer. With this you can parse the number `9` (or whichever piece you need for sorting) from the string `9º (2017 a 2020)`. You can then use this number as the data to use when the column is sorted. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66859337/add-exception-to-natural-sorting-in-datatables/66860664#66860664) for an example.

Comment: Another (similar) option is to use `orderData` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60918299/datatables-sorting-how-to-ignore-text-in-column/60918789#60918789). There are also more advanced [custom sorting](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/sorting) techniques - but you probably don't need that here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is down to the contents of each of the table cells and `DataTable` treating all content as strings in Column 0 and 1 (due to the mixed nature of the content). Column 1 doesn't *appear* to have issues, but that's because there are no cells starting with a 2-digit number. Column 3 contains only date data so works fine.

The fix for column 0 (and should also be applied to column 1) is to make use of the `data-*` attributes (https://datatables.net/manual/data/). So, hopefully whatever is rendering the contents of the `<td>` cells would be updated to include a `data-order` attribute with cell data up to "º". You could do something like `cellContents.split("º")[0]`, where `cellContents` is the text that would appear in a cell.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "iDisplayLength": 50,
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "responsive": true,
    } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
            <td data-order="9">9º (2017 a 2020)</td>
            <td>2º (2019 a 2020)</td>
            <td class="center">18/08/2021 às 23:49:02</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td data-order="9">9º (2017 a 2020)</td>
            <td>1º (2017 a 2018)</td>
            <td class="center">18/08/2021 às 23:48:49</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
            <td data-order="8">8º (2013 a 2016)</td>
            <td>2º (2015 a 2016)</td>
            <td class="center">18/08/2021 às 23:48:39</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td data-order="8">8º (2013 a 2016)</td>
            <td>1º (2013 a 2014)</td>
            <td class="center">18/08/2021 às 23:48:29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
            <td data-order="7">7º (2009 a 2012)</td>
            <td>2º (2011 a 2012)</td>
            <td class="center">18/08/2021 às 23:48:19</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td data-order="7">7º (2009 a 2012)</td>
            <td>1º (2009 a 2010)</td>
            <td class="center">18/08/2021 às 23:48:08</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
            <td data-order="6">6º (2005 a 2008)</td>
            <td>2º (2007 a 2008)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:21:20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td data-order="6">6º (2005 a 2008)</td>
            <td>1º (2005 a 2006)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:20:15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
            <td data-order="5">5º (2001 a 2004)</td>
            <td>2º (2003 a 2004)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:22:09</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td data-order="5">5º (2001 a 2004)</td>
            <td>1º (2001 a 2002)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:21:44</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
            <td data-order="4">4º (1997 a 2000)</td>
            <td>2º (1999 a 2000)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:23:49</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td data-order="4">4º (1997 a 2000)</td>
            <td>1º (1997 a 1998)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:22:39</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
            <td data-order="3">3º (1993 a 1996)</td>
            <td>2º (1995 a 1996)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:24:45</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td data-order="3">3º (1993 a 1996)</td>
            <td>2º (1995 a 1996)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:25:39</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
            <td data-order="3">3º (1993 a 1996)</td>
            <td>1º (1993 a 1994)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:24:21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td data-order="3">3º (1993 a 1996)</td>
            <td>1º (1993 a 1994)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:25:18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
            <td data-order="10">10º (2021 a 2024)</td>
            <td>2º (2023 a 2024)</td>
            <td class="center">27/08/2021 às 12:18:35</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td data-order="10">10º (2021 a 2024)</td>
            <td>1º (2021 a 2022)</td>
            <td class="center">18/08/2021 às 23:49:12</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th>ANO</th>
            <th>BIÊNIO</th>
            <th>DATA DE CADASTRO</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: And how do I put the data-order when the result comes via json?

"aoColumns": [
                { title: "#",sClass: "center",
      "data": function (data) {
      return(data.date);
      }
    }
    { title: "ID", data: "id", sClass: "center"},
   ]

Comment: Is the original question answered?

Comment: It worked perfectly accommodating the data in

<td data-order="7">7th (2009 to 2012)</td>

Thanks!

Comment: When the result comes via json, how do I put data-order on the column/line?

Comment: Ideally, you just want something that transforms your JSON into html dynamically, and the solution varies based on your current "framework". Can you generate files server-side? Are you using something like React to generate content, etc? The solution really does vary on what you're currently doing